# Consuming RestFul Wcf Service in Sliverlight Client

Tags: wcf, silverlight

I have a RestFul Wcf Service created.It needs to be consumed in sliverlight client, dont want to create proxy of service. Method should be using URI.

What i have tried so far is using WebClient to make a request, but it throws Target invocation Exception.

Here is my code snippet:

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 wc.OpenReadCompleted+=wc_OpenReadCompleted;
 wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/RC2/XXX/SampleService.svc/GetHello"));
```

SampleService is a service with GetHello GET method

wc_OpenReadCompleted is call back for the request which gives me error of Target invocation

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @ Faizan Mubasher : using WebClient[i have not got any good tutorial on that] but it give outter exception as System.Reflection.TargetInvokationException and inner exception as Security exception .......... but using web client is not a established way on using Restful wcf ...... any established method of communication is welcomed

Comment: Pate your code bro. It helps to determine problem.

Comment: WebClient wc = new WebClient();
     wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new    DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
     wc.OpenReadCompleted+=wc_OpenReadCompleted;
                    wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://localhost/RC2/UI/SL/Clustering/Cluster.svc/GetHello"));

Comment: Cluster.svc is wcf service with GetHello method

Comment: You can edit your question.